# How to encourage sparsity of a tensor using L1 regularisation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

From [tensorflow documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/regularizers.py#L231-L244), I see there are a few ways of applying L1 regularisation. The first is the most intuitive to me. This example behaves as expected, d1 has all 3's, which sum up to 48 and scaled by 0.1 we get 4.8 as the loss.

```
d1 = tf.ones(shape=(2,2,4))*3
regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.1)
regularizer(d1)
```

> tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.8

In the second way, we use the regularisation on kernels. So I'm guessing it encourages sparsity of model weights. I can't exactly tell how the loss is 0.54747146.

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,input_dim=(2,2,4),kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.1))
out = layer(d1)
layer.losses
```

> tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.54747146

The third way I believed should have given the same result as the first way of applying regularisation directly to the layer. Here we use `activity_regularizer`: Regularizer to apply a penalty on the layer's output.

```
layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,input_dim=(2,2,4),activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.1))
out2=layer2(d1)
layer2.losses
```

> tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.4821562

** *The value returned by the `activity_regularizer` is divided by the input
  batch size...*

Why is the loss 1.4821562? It seems to be different every time I repeat. How do the third and first ways differ?

**If I want to encourage sparsity of d1, which should I use?**

Comment: ```Dense``` initializes the weights from ```glorot_uniform``` (hence random l1). Try using ```kernel_initializer='ones'```.

Answer (score 1):

What your dense layer is calculating is a matrix product 
`y = W x + b`. Your three different ways of applying L1 calculate:

1. `l1(x)`
2. `l1(W)`
3. `l1(Wx + b)`

Since the weights and biases are randomly generated, they will be different for each run unless you specify a fixed seed.

Comment: and if I want sparsity in x, I go for 1 isn't it?

Comment: In your example, x is `d1 = tf.ones(shape=(2,2,4))*3`, which is a constant, so I'm not sure what you want to achieve here.
Also note that example 1) does not add the l1 regularization loss to the model, so e.g. `keras.Model.fit` is not aware of this loss.

Comment: not in this example of course, but in general in a more practical network, if I am adding the loss etc. it should be the correct method to use? Just not very sure.

Comment: I think a practical example will typically lead you to either 2) or 3). If `x` is the result of a previous layer, applying 3) to that layer is the same as using 1) for the following layer, but with the added benefit that keras will take care of loss tracking.

It is difficult to say more without a concrete example.